# Javascript: Adding number types gets me NaN

Tags: javascript, html, numbers, nan

I'll preface this with sorry, I'm a complete noob and I just don't understand what is happening.

I'm adding two variables of type number (I checked), and when I print the outcome, I get NaN. :(

More context: I want to add an existing number on my page (3, in the HTML here) to whatever the user inputs, in real time. I can retrieve these numbers fine, and when I check their types, it returns "number". But when I assign a variable to their sum I get NaN. I feel like I'm missing something stupid.

The javascript:

```
window.onload = setupHandlers;

function getBanana() {
console.log("hi getBAnana is running")
var quantity = document.getElementById("Banana");
var howmany = 0;
if(quantity.value!="") {
  howmany = parseInt(quantity.value);
}

console.log(howmany);
var total = document.getElementById("total").innerHTML;
console.log(total);
oldtotal = parseInt(total.value);
console.log("oldtotal type: " + typeof oldtotal);
console.log("howmany: " + howmany);
console.log("howmany type: " + typeof howmany);
newtotal = oldtotal + howmany;

console.log("newtotal type: " + typeof newtotal);
console.log(newtotal);
}

function setupHandlers(){
   var Banana = document.getElementById("Banana");
   Banana.onchange = getBanana;
}

The HTML:
 <!-- some form code and other tags here blabla-->
    <input type="number" id="Banana" min="0" placeholder="lbs">
    <span id= "total">3</span>
    <script src="jstest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `total.value` will be undefined a there is no method of `document.getElementById("total").innerHTML;`. Refer this: https://jsfiddle.net/seLqboqn/

Answer (score 2):

`total` is a string. Strings do not have `.value`, so `total.value` is `undefined`. `parseInt(undefined)` is `NaN`, which is a `number` even though it is not a number (JavaScript is full of old warts). When you add `NaN` and any other number, you still get a `NaN`.

You need `parseInt(total)`.

Also, since `3` is not HTML, it would be better to use `.textContent` and not `.innerHTML`.